# efficient updating of variables

Tags: python, input

I am recording the input from a serial connection.

At the moment, I have been using a basic class that the input is run through updating `self.min & self.max`

But perhaps there is a more efficient way to do this?

perhaps a deque? would this have efficiency benefits?
perhaps a class is not needed?

---

An example of one that I have used:

```
class RangeFinder(object):

    def __init__(self, _mem=3) :
        self._mem = deque(maxlen=_mem)
        self.absmax = -10**10
        self.absmin = 10**10
        self.relmax = None
        self.relmin = None

    def read(self, _data) :
        if _data != None:
            self._mem.append(_data)
            if len(self._mem) == self._mem.maxlen :       
                self.relmax = max(self._mem)
                self.absmax = max(self.absmax, self.relmax)      
                self.relmin = min(self._mem)    
                self.absmin = min(self.absmin, self.relmin)
```

another idea:

```
class MinMax(deque):

    def __init__(self):
        deque.__init__(self, [ 10**10, -10**10 ], maxlen=2)

    def read(self, _data):
        if _data < self[0]:
            self.popleft()
            self.appendleft(_data)
        if _data > self[1]:
            self.pop()
            self.append(_data)
```

input is a string that is converted to an int. I have only recently begun using the serial connection as a generator so there are some discrepancies.

The min and max are then used to calculate the intensity of a lazer for reading binary data.

Comment: Describe the format and purpose of your input. Also, can you show us what you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for a bisection here to maintain the order when you input data. So that the lookup for the min/max will be O(1) and the load would go on the insertion (O(nlogn)). Also I don't think you need a class here, you can safely implement only functions (if the problem is as you described it).

```
>>> import random
>>> import bisect
>>> data = []
>>> input_data = random.sample(range(1000),100) 
>>> #Substitute this with your serial input data
>>> for i in input_data:
...     bisect.insort(data, i)
>>> min = data[0]
>>> max = data[-1]
```

Comment: if the input is a constant (say 1000 ints a second), would a deque with a max length work the same? Obviously I don't want a list 100,000 items long :)